# IntelliJ..how do you even import an existing Java Application?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I been using JGrasp as I could not for the life of me figure out how to implement pre-made java files to either Eclipse or IntelliJ. But now I am trying to figure it out but I am getting really confused.

So for IntelliJ its just

```
File > Open - then your existing java application
```

but then everything has red icon so I found out fix is

```
File > Project Structure > Modules > Sources
```

but then..need to set output path..so found out fix is

```
File > Project Structure > Modules > Paths > Inherit.
```

but it was already on by default so I have to use module

```
Then you set JDK to the one you have on your computer
```

But then I get the Error `Main` not found..**I'm assuming its from the set Output part** but I really do not get it :/

I know for a fact is not the code as it works normally in JGrasp so I'm really not sure.

**Side Questions:**

> 1. Do I have to do this every single time even if I'm just trying to drag and drop one pre-made Java Application?
> 2. Does this also allow the use of Applets? Or do I have to include something else to the library?[Found Answer]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Import project?
[image: IntelliJ 2016.1 start screen]

Right click in the main method an there you see 2 run targets for the main class (run and debug). If you do this once you find the run configuration at the top. (See the small  arrow at the top of the second picture next to "Testmain". There you can switch between run configs and edit them.

[image: Run configurations]

Comment: I just did right after taking the screenshot. Not easy to update all 5 IDEs and plugin at once ;)

Comment: Ohhh, didn't realize there was a difference. Guess that means I would have to import everytime I want to run seperate Java Applications with there own `main`

Comment: @confusedpanda: Added run configs explanation to my answer. You have to do this once for every project, if a project has multiple Main methods you should (must) use run configurations